Como enviar params a un programa en C#
bueno tengo este codigo que abre un .exe de un programa de terceros que no manejo:
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string pathToWpfApp = @"C:\Program Files\desarrollo\Proyecto.exe";
    
    string parametro = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" ?>" +
                    "<Raiz>" +
                    "...." +
                    "Formulario=\"Formulario_1\" " +
                    "..." +
                    "</Raiz>";

    startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = pathToWpfApp,
        Arguments = parametro,
        UseShellExecute = true
    };
    
    Process.Start(startInfo);    
}

Lo que hace es abrir un programa, le envio como parámetro un xml que en la linea Formulario recibe una ventana que abre, la cuestion es que hasta ahi me funciona de maravilla, instancia el programa y luego le carga el formulario.
pero ya una vez abierto la idea es enviarle que cargue el Formulario_2 o el Formulario_3, pero no se como hacer para que desde C# solo sea cambiarle el parametro del xml y enviarle ese string a un exe abierto, NO necesito instanciar uno nuevo, solo enviarle un param al Proyecto.exe que ya esta abierto.
He mirado por todo lado y no he podido, tambien con iA y no me da respuesta

¿Cómo pasas el parámetro? ¿En la misma llamada o primero instancias la app y luego le pasas el parámetro? Habría que analizar las posibilidades que ofrece dicha app. Explicate un poco más

Ahi mismo en ese metodo que comparti, creo la ruta donde esta el exe, le creo los params, cargo todo en startInfo y esta linea: Process.Start(startInfo); abre el .exe con los params... ya una vez abierto el programa ¿como le envio otros params sin necesidad de abrir de nuevo el .exe?

si el programa de terceros permite hacerlo pues por ahí es la solución, es el programa de terceros el que debe estar programado para recibir mas xml una vez este en ejecución. O sea tu como externo puedes usar el programa tal cual esta hecho, no le puedes inventar funcionalidades

En tu Proyecto.exe usas Mutex para detectar una nueva instancia
private static readonly string APP_NAME = "Algun_nombre_unico";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using Mutex mutex = new(true, APP_NAME, out var isNewInstance);
        
    if (isNewInstance)
    {
        //No existe `Proyecto.exe` abierto, este es el primero en abrir
    }
    else
    {
        //hay otro `Proyecto.exe` abierto
    }
        
}

Abres el primer Proyecto.exe y todo bien, ahora abres un segundo Proyecto.exe, este detecta que no es el primero (con mutex), por lo que debe enviar la información (el string[] args) al primero. Para ello puedes usar NamedPipeClientStream, que es una especie de servicio cliente/servidor muy simple de usar. Luego de enviar esta información, se cierra el segundo Proyecto.exe. Y de esta manera, todo está controlado por la primera instancia en abrirse, ejemplo:
private static readonly string APP_NAME = "Algun_nombre_unico";

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    using Mutex mutex = new(true, APP_NAME, out var isNewInstance);
        
    if (isNewInstance)
    {
        Task.Run(RunPipeServer); //Es la primera instancia, abrimos el servidor
        ProcesarParams(args); //procesamos los argumentos entregados
        Console.ReadLine(); //evitamos que se cierra la consola
    }
    else
    {
        //Es otra instancia, enviamos los argumentos a la primera
        using NamedPipeClientStream client = new(".", APP_NAME, PipeDirection.Out);
        client.Connect(1000); 
        using StreamWriter writer = new(client) { AutoFlush =true };
        writer.WriteLine(string.Join(" ",args));  
    }
        
}

static void RunPipeServer()
{
       
    while (true)
    {
        using NamedPipeServerStream server = new(APP_NAME, PipeDirection.In);
        server.WaitForConnection();
        using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(server);
        ProcesarParams(reader.ReadLine());
        server.Disconnect(); // Preparar para recibir otro mensaje
    }
        
}

//función que procesa lo entregado en el argumento, en tu caso el XML
static void ProcesarParams(params string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", args));
}


epa! es practicamente lo que estaba buscando. lo unico es que el "Proyecto.exe" que menciono, no es mio, yo no controlo ese codigo ni tengo acceso. Es que el se abre e internamente despliega una ventana, que es el parametro "Formulario" que le envio en el xml, y la idea es que cada que le envie el param abra el formulario que le envie en xml, no que abra una nueva ventana con el otro formulario... y la cuestion es que lo unico que conozco de ese .exe es que el recibe ese xml no mas, asi que no puedo agregar las lineas que dices, pero puedo mas o menos ver como lo implemento desde mi codigo
